# Initialized variable before MPI_Init() and cout after MPI_Finanlize()

Tags: c++, linux, mpi

I have been testing how exactly mpi works with the following code

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <mpi.h>
    using namespace std;
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    r = 3.0;
    int id; 
    int p;
    int a[100];
    for(int i=0;i<100;++i){a[i]=i+5; }
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);

    cout<<id<<"   "<<r<<"   "<<a[id]<<endl;

    MPI_Finalize();

    cout<< "Hello world " <<endl;

    return 0;
    }
```

I am using 30 cores to run the code. but the output is somehow surprising on 2 aspects,

1. Here this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20527338/mpi-and-global-variables) says that if you initialize a variable before MPI_Init(), the other process but 0 will be blind about the initialized value, but in my output file all the process of different ids output the r=3 and the correct value for `a[i]`, so does this mean that I can initialize a variable or an array before calling MPI_Init() and all processes will share the same value for that variable?
2. The output has a lot of lines of "Hello world " which apparently indicates that each process is printing "Hello world " even after calling MPI_Finalize(), why is that?

By the way, I am using mpicc for compiling the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's perfectly valid to execute code before `MPI_Init` and after `MPI_Finalize`. Of course you are not allowed to use MPI in that code, but otherwise it's just normal C++.

`MPI_Init` and `MPI_Finalize` are just library calls, they are not supposed to change control flow or remove values assigned prior to init (and how would that be possible at all?).

`MPI_Init` doesn't cancel initialization of variables.

The question you're referring to is saying just that initialization in process 0 doesn't initialize values in other processes. In that question, data were read from file which probably existed only for process 0.

Note that `MPI_Init` doesn't create new process. It's not like `fork`. All the processes are created before your program starts (most likely by `mpirun`). And in your case, each process initializes its array.

`MPI_Finalize` doesn't terminate the process. It only shuts down the MPI library. Processes still continue running after that, although they cannot interact any more.

Comment: Thanks. I got the 1st part. But what should I do if I just want to print one line of "Hello World ", the one in my mind is that `if(id==0)cout<<"Hello world "<<endl`, besides this one, how can I print one line by terminating the process?

Comment: You proposed a perfect solution: if you need only the 0th process to do something, check its rank (and of course value in `id` survives `MPI_Finalize`). I am not aware of any other way of distinguishing MPI processes.

Comment: I thought `MPI_Abort` would work. But after trying I found that after calling `MPI_Abort` even the main process(id=0) terminates, it doesn't print at all.

Comment: Yes, MPI_Abort terminates all processes. `if (id == 0)` is the easiest and the sanest way to do something in the 'main' process. (By the way, all processes are equal, I think it's just conventional that we are calling the 0th process 'main'. It doesn't have any specific privileges, it's not a parent for all other processes, it's just one of them.)

Comment: As a matter of fact, rank 0 is special in many MPI implementations. For example, redirection of the standard input of `mpiexec` happens only to rank 0 - no other rank can get input from `stdin` / `cin`. This behaviour applies to Open MPI, as well as to MPICH and its derivatives, and possibly to many other implementations. Some MPI implementations allow I/O only from rank 0 or from some other specific rank. The standard defines some attributes on `MPI_COMM_WORLD` that can be queried to find things out.

Comment: Also, it's actually possible that some implementations wouldn't allow code to be executed at all before `MPI_INIT` or after `MPI_FINALIZE`. I believe FG-MPI does this since it actually does implement MPI ranks as threads which are `fork`/`join`'ed at `INIT`/`FINALIZE`.