# gfortran and random numbers

Tags: random, fortran, gfortran

I am trying to compile the following simple code using Gfortran 4.7 from mac-ports (OS-X):

```
program main

implicit none

integer :: n = 1, clock, i

integer, dimension(1) :: iseed

! initialize the random number generator
call random_seed(size = n)

call system_clock(COUNT=clock)

iseed = clock + 37 * (/ (i - 1, i = 1, n) /)
! iseed = clock
! iseed = abs( mod((clock*181)*((1-83)*359), 104729) )
call random_seed(PUT = iseed)

end program main
```

and have this error:

```
gfortran-mp-4.7  tmp.f90
tmp.f90:17.23:

call random_seed(PUT = iseed)
                   1
Error: Size of 'put' argument of 'random_seed' intrinsic at (1) too small (1/12)
```

I don't use Fortran at all (I am a C++ guy), so would really appreciate if someone could help and make it working.

p.s. On a similar issue i found couple of forum posts, the current uncomment solution is similar to the one mentioned in [this GCC bug report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39266).

The one with `abs` is mentioned [in this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920411/possible-sources-for-random-number-seeds) (added it without PID since i don't run in parallel anyway.

UPDATE:

the following works:

```
program main

implicit none

integer :: n = 12, clock, i

integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: iseed

! initialize the random number generator
allocate(iseed(n))
call random_seed(size = n)

call system_clock(COUNT=clock)

iseed = clock + 37 * [(i, i = 0,n-1)]
call random_seed(PUT = iseed)

end program main
```

Comment: The GCC bug report you link to has the solution: you need to set `n = 12` and `integer, dimension(12) :: iseed`. The `put` argument to `random_seed` requires an array of 12 integers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To amplify somewhat on @Yossarian's comment, this

```
call random_seed(size = n)
```

returns, in `n`, the size of the rank 1 integer array that you have to use if you want to initialise the RNG. I'd suggest making `iseed` allocatable by changing its declaration to:

```
integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: iseed
```

then, after getting a value for `n`, allocate it:

```
allocate(iseed(n))
```

populate it with your favourite values, then `put` it.

You might be able to allocate and populate it in one statement like this:

```
allocate(iseed(n), source = clock + 37 * [(i, i = 0,n-1)])
```

I write *might* because this depends on how up to date your compiler is.

EDIT, after OP comment

No, you have not quite understood what I suggested.

Get a value for `n` by executing

```
call random_seed(size = n)
```

don't initialise `n` to 12.

Then allocate the array and populate it, either in one statement (using sourced allocation) or an `allocate` statement followed by an assignment.

In

```
allocate(iseed(n))
call random_seed(size = n)
```

the sequence of operations is incorrect.  This sets `iseed` to have 12 elements (which is the value of `n` when the first statement is executed), and then sets `n` to the size of the array required by the RNG.  So long as that is 12 you won't see any problems, but as soon as you port your code to another compiler, possibly even another version of the same compiler, you risk running into an RNG which requires an integer array of a different size. There is no need to hardwire a value into your code, so don't.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I put the update code, is it what you meant? I does compile fine