# Why are initial random numbers similar when using similar seeds?

Tags: java, random

I discovered something strange with the generation of random numbers using Java's Random class.
Basically, if you create multiple Random objects using close seeds (for example between 1 and 1000) the first value generated by each generator will be almost the same, but the next values looks fine (i didn't search further).

Here are the two first generated doubles with seeds from 0 to 9 :

- 0 0.730967787376657 0.24053641567148587
- 1 0.7308781907032909 0.41008081149220166
- 2 0.7311469360199058 0.9014476240300544
- 3 0.731057369148862 0.07099203475193139
- 4 0.7306094602878371 0.9187140138555101
- 5 0.730519863614471 0.08825840967622589
- 6 0.7307886238322471 0.5796252073129174
- 7 0.7306990420600421 0.7491696031336331
- 8 0.7302511331990172 0.5968915822372118
- 9 0.7301615514268123 0.7664359929590888

And from 991 to 1000 :

- 991 0.7142160704801332 0.9453385235522973
- 992 0.7109015598097105 0.21848118381994108
- 993 0.7108119780375055 0.38802559454181795
- 994 0.7110807233541204 0.8793923921785096
- 995 0.7109911564830766 0.048936787999225295
- 996 0.7105432327208906 0.896658767102804
- 997 0.7104536509486856 0.0662031629235198
- 998 0.7107223962653005 0.5575699754613725
- 999 0.7106328293942568 0.7271143712820883
- 1000 0.7101849056320707 0.574836350385667

And here is a figure showing the first value generated with seeds from 0 to 100,000.

First random double generated based on the seed :

[image]

I searched for information about this, but I didn't see anything referring to this precise problem. I know that there is many issues with LCGs algorithms, but I didn't know about this one, and I was wondering if this was a known issue.

And also, do you know if this problem only for the first value (or first few values), or if it is more general and using close seeds should be avoided?

Thanks.

Comment: Both C++ and Java has standard pseudo-random generators. Pseudo-->not fully random.

Comment: I think using seeds in general reduces randomness. You should try to make your seed as random as possible, ideally not use one at all. ;) Many of the SecureRandom implementations ignore the seed provided.

Comment: There are many randomizing functions

Comment: You do realize what "seeds" do right? This isn't a hashing function, don't expect radically different results at the same time using slightly different seeds.

Comment: The thing is that I usually need my runs to be reproducible, so I need to use a seed based generator. Also I know that it is not fully random, but that is not the result I expect even from a pseudo random generator :/

Comment: You might find this interesting. http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/randomly-no-so-random.html If you want to use seeds, you need to be careful which ones you use. Note: Random only uses 48-bits of the seed and won't generate every possible `long` or `double` as a result.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426350/seeding-java-util-random-with-consecutive-numbers

Comment: I was wondering if Python has the same problem. [Python does not have the same problem](https://github.com/MartinThoma/algorithms/tree/master/Python/random)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You'd be best served by downloading and reading the `Random` source, as well as some papers on pseudo-random generators, but here are some of the relevant parts of the source. To begin with, there are three constant parameters that control the algorithm:

```
private final static long multiplier = 0x5DEECE66DL;
private final static long addend = 0xBL;
private final static long mask = (1L << 48) - 1;
```

The multiplier works out to approximately 2^34 and change, the mask 2^48 - 1, and the addend is pretty close to 0 for this analysis.

When you create a Random with a seed, the constructor calls `setSeed`:

```
synchronized public void setSeed(long seed) {
    seed = (seed ^ multiplier) & mask;
    this.seed.set(seed);
    haveNextNextGaussian = false;
}
```

You're providing a seed pretty close to zero, so initial seed value that gets set is dominated by `multiplier` when the two are OR'ed together. In all your test cases with seeds close to zero, the seed that is used internally is roughly 2^34; but it's easy to see that even if you provided very large seed numbers, similar user-provided seeds will yield similar internal seeds.

The final piece is the `next(int)` method, which actually generates a random integer of the requested length based on the current seed, and then updates the seed:

```
protected int next(int bits) {
    long oldseed, nextseed;
    AtomicLong seed = this.seed;
    do {
    oldseed = seed.get();
    nextseed = (oldseed * multiplier + addend) & mask;
    } while (!seed.compareAndSet(oldseed, nextseed));
    return (int)(nextseed >>> (48 - bits));
}
```

This is called a 'linear congruential' pseudo-random generator, meaning that it generates each successive seed by multiplying the current seed by a constant multiplier and then adding a constant addend (and then masking to take the lower 48 bits, in this case). The quality of the generator is determined by the choice of multiplier and addend, but the ouput from all such generators can be easily predicted based on the current input and has a set period before it repeats itself (hence the recommendation not to use them in sensitive applications).

The reason you're seeing similar initial output from `nextDouble` given similar seeds is that, because the computation of the next integer only involves a multiplication and addition, the magnitude of the next integer is not much affected by differences in the lower bits. Calculation of the next double involves computing a large integer based on the seed and dividing it by another (constant) large integer, and the magnitude of the result is mostly affected by the magnitude of the integer.

Repeated calculations of the next seed will magnify the differences in the lower bits of the seed because of the repeated multiplication by the constant multiplier, and because the 48-bit mask throws out the highest bits each time, until eventually you see what looks like an even spread.

Comment: Why does this have so few upvotes and the question have so many? Awesome answer!

Comment: Is there a workaround other than always call nextDouble() twice after seeding a random?

Comment: I think there is a typo, (seed ^ multiplier) is XOR but you refer to it as "OR"

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't have called this an "issue".

> And also, do you know if this problem only for the first value (or first few values), or if it is more general and using close seeds should be avoided?

Correlation patterns between successive numbers is a common problem with non-crypto PRNGs, and this is just one manifestation.  The correlation (strictly auto-correlation) is inherent in the mathematics underlying the algorithm(s).  If you want to understand that, you should probably start by reading the relevant part of Knuth's Art of Computer Programming Chapter 3.

If you need non-predictability you should use a (true) random seed for `Random` ... or let the system pick a "pretty random" one for you; e.g. using the no-args constructor.  Or better still, use a real random number source or a crypto-quality PRNG instead of `Random`.

---

For the record:

1. The javadoc (Java 7) does not specify how Random() seeds itself.
2. The implementation of `Random()` on Java 7 for Linux, is seeded from the nanosecond clock, XORed with a 'uniquifier' sequence.  The 'uniquifier' sequence is LCG which uses different multiplier, and whose state is static. This is intended to avoid auto-correlation of the seeds ...

Comment: The no-arg constructor uses `System.currentTimeMillis()` as the seed, so different instances of the `Random` class instantiated around the same time will return correlated values still. I would modify the last paragraph to mention using `SecureRandom` instead.

Comment: The only way this answer could be better is if it actually explained the math behind this correlation.

Comment: @ErickRobertson - that is too much to ask of a non-mathematician :-)

Comment: @mattb - 1) the javadoc (Java 7) does not specify how `Random()` seeds itself. 2) on Java 7 for Linux, it is seeded from the nanosecond clock, XORed with a 'uniquifier' sequence that is implemented using a different LCG whose state is `static`.  This is intended to avoid auto-correlation of the seeds ...

Comment: @StephenC that's interesting, without realizing it what version I was looking at my Google search brought me to [the 1.4.2 docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random()), which do specify that `currentTimeMillis()` is used. Looks like they changed the description way back in JDK5. Also on OS X JDK 6 the constructor looks like `public Random() { this(++seedUniquifier + System.nanoTime()); }` which I don't believe would be an XOR operation.

Comment: @mattb - It is XORed in Java 7, and the uniquifier is more complicated.  Trust me ... or download and read the source code.  And don't rely on ancient 1.4.2 javadocs :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly typical behaviour for pseudo-random seeds - they aren't required to provide completely different random sequences, they only provide a guarantee that you can get the same sequence again if you use the same seed.

The behaviour happens because of the mathematical form of the PRNG - the Java one uses a linear congruential generator, so you are just seeing the results running the seed through one round of the linear congruential generator. This isn't enough to completely mix up all the bit patterns, hence you see similar results for similar seeds.

Your best strategy is probably just to use very different seeds - one option would be to obtain these by hashing the seed values that you are currently using.

Answer (score -1):

By making random seeds (for instance, using some mathematical functions on System.currentTimeMillis() or System.nanoTime() for seed generation) you can get better random result. Also can look at [here](http://javamex.com/tutorials/random_numbers/seeding.shtml) for more information

Comment: -1 This doesn't answer the question.  It seems the OP is aware of this, but is using fixed seeds so he can reproduce the results.