# scala.util.Random generates nearly identical doubles with different seeds

Tags: scala, random, sampling

I came across something in `scala.util.Random` that led me to unnecessary debugging yesterday.

I just needed random `Doubles`, and so used `scala.util.Random`. For similar seeds (i.e., integers `0 ... N` ), I found that the first call to `nextDouble()` returned almost identical values; for my purposes of sampling a binned CDF, they were *identical*.

```
import scala.util.Random
val seed = 1 to 10
val nums = seed.map(u => new Random(u).nextDouble)
```

Result:

```
Vector(0.7308781907032909, 0.7311469360199058, 0.731057369148862, 0.7306094602878371, 0.730519863614471, 0.7307886238322471, 0.7306990420600421, 0.7302511331990172, 0.7301615514268123, 0.7304302967434272)
```

Is there something I'm not aware of about the `scala.util.Random`? Getting almost the same value for different seeds seems very strange to me.

Comment: This is essentially answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12284419/334519), since `scala.util.Random` is a very thin wrapper around `java.util.Random`.

Comment: Also some good information here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1554995/1223622

Comment: Thanks---I should have searched for the issue in Java too.

Comment: @modulus0 It's a reasonable question, especially since there's nothing in the `scala.util.Random` docs to indicate that it's just a wrapper around `java.util.Random`.