# Does the difference between random seeds matter?

Tags: java, random

Will this:

```
new java.util.Random(/* random seed */ 0)
new java.util.Random(/* random seed */ 1)
```

result in somehow "less random" / "more similar" random generators than this?

```
new java.util.Random(/* random seed */ 0)
new java.util.Random(/* random seed */ 1000)
```

In other words: do I risk having similar series of ints obtained from the random generators if their random seeds are similar?

Comment: It's not "less" or "more" random.  It's just differently random.

Comment: You should really give [How good is java.util.Random](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453479/how-good-is-java-util-random) a read.  It discusses the strengths (no weak seeds) and weaknesses (not actually all that random) of the Random class.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282628/why-are-initial-random-numbers-similar-when-using-similar-seeds should be mentioned here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, similar seeds, will not produce similar random numbers.
Only same seeds will produce same numbers.

The code to set the seed is:

```
void setSeed(long seed) {
    this.seed = (seed ^ 0x5DEECE66DL) & ((1L << 48) - 1);
..}
```

This formula avoids that `this.seed` gets simlar values for the input seed value (used in the constructor, or by setSeed().

However there is some weakness, als explained in 
http://dontpanic.42.nl/2011/03/when-random-isn-as-random-as-expected.html

Answer (score 1):

The state updates used to produce pseudo-random numbers are [chaotic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory).  Hence, using adjacent seed values results in entirely different state trajectories.

Answer (score 0):

Random numbers are never random. They are entirely pre-defined and given the same seed will always result in the same numbers even over a million different runs of the commands, that is the reason they are called ["Pseudorandom"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandomness). The best thing to do is to seed with a value that will be different each time the program is run and can not be predicted easily such as the current time and date and/or number of clock cycles that have passed.

Comment: This was not the question. He wants to know if two adjacent seeds produce similar random numbers.

Comment: And I explained that they never produce random numbers. That is indeed an answer to the question.

Comment: Not it is not. You need to explain the effect of the input seed for two adjacent seed, and their effect, to the output random numbers.